# How can I change the order of a 2D Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, machine-learning, data-science

Hi guys I have really simple question for you, let me explain shortly, for more detailed explanation please read below.

**I want to order my 2D array which is an array of coordinates.** However k= np.sort(k,0) is not working for me since it causes shuffling of y values. How can I solve this problem without losing my y values in an array of (x,y) ?

[image]

On the above you can see the result of np.sort(). It sorts all columns and shuffling the values, this makes the data useless.

**Here is a longer explanation why I need that order:**

I have a 2D array which are centers for K-means

```
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c='black', s=200, alpha=0.5);
```

[image]

I would like to sort this array with their x values because I want to use this in a RBF function like this:

```
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c='black', s=200, alpha=0.5);

rbfi = Rbf(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1],function='gaussian')
u = rbfi(centers[:,0])
plt.plot(centers[:,0],u,'orange',linewidth=4)
plt.tick_params(labelcolor = 'white')
```

[image]

Since it is not ordered the function takes 2D points randomly and try to draw a line between them.

**The result should look like something like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to keep the index unchanged. If that assumption is correct, I would suggest a dataframe, sorted with "inplace=True":

```
import dataframe as df
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': your_x_numpy_array, 'y': your_y_numpy_array})
df.sort_values(by=[your_index_of_choice],inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much using pandas saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer similar as [@Hayden Eastwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3235260/hayden-eastwood)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': centers[:,0], 'y': centers[:,1]})
df = df.sort_values(by='x')
centers = pd.DataFrame(df).to_numpy()
```

And result:

[image]